# Sequential Forward Selection in Python, problem with feature names?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

why after using `sffs.k_feature_names_` I do not have names of best column but only their position ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the [example on the documentation](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/feature_selection/SequentialFeatureSelector/#example-1-a-simple-sequential-forward-selection-example):

> Note that the 'feature_names' entry is simply a string representation of the 'feature_idx' in this case. Optionally, we can provide custom feature names via the `fit` method's `custom_feature_names` parameter